# Add point to a PDF Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, kotlin, draw

I'm currently developing an application on Android with AndroidPDFViewer :

I want to create a functionality, when the user touch the screen, it put a point on the PDF at this location. After I want to measure the distance between 2 points but it's an other problem.
I don't understand how to do this functionality, put a point on PDF. I found this : https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/554
So it's possible but how ? I don't get it.
I suppose I need to create a bitmap.

Currently, I have this : 
`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf)
    val pdfName = intent.getStringExtra("pdfName")
    openPdf(pdfName)


    mLayout = findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
    l = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rl)
    child = l?.getChildAt(1)!!

    child?.isEnabled = false

    var mesureButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.mesureButton)
    mesureButton.setOnClickListener{
        child?.isEnabled = true
        val bitmap: Bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(child?.width!!, child?.height!!, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas: Canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        var shapeDrawable: ShapeDrawable
        shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(RectShape())
        shapeDrawable.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200)
        shapeDrawable.paint.color = Color.parseColor("#009944")
        shapeDrawable.draw(canvas)
        (child as ImageView)?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())
        shapeDrawable.setBounds(600, 600, 650, 650)
        shapeDrawable.paint.color = Color.parseColor("#009944")
        shapeDrawable.draw(canvas)
        (child as ImageView)?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        child?.isEnabled = false

    }


fun openPdf(pdfName: String) {
    pdf = findViewById(R.id.pdf) as PDFView
    val f = File(pdfName)
    pdf?.fromFile(f)!!.load()`
```

Here, when i push my button , I draw 2 shapes for test but the shape doesn't stay at the right position of the pdf. When I scroll, it moves.

I spend my week on it and search but I don't get it.
And I can't use https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid to have a image because when I zoom on it, it's blurry.
I'm desperate ahah.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you zoom in on something, it generally gets blurry. It's because you're making the size of the pixels change but maintaining the same, possibly low resolution. Zoom blur isn't just a problem with that library, it's a general problem